# send information in database from html page to another one

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask html page that retrieve applicants information from the database sqlalchemy, I want to click on a name of applicant from the first page and another page open with specific information for this applicant.

I sent a query for the first page and it works like I want, but I struggled in the second page, I did not know how to send that one record

this is the code of the first page, applicant-report page is the second page

```
{% for report in reports %}
      <div class="rec_box">
          <a class="text" href="/applicant-report">
            {% for a in applicant %}
            {% if a.phone == report.applicant_phone %}
            {{a.name}}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </a>
          <p class="rec_small">O: {{(report.op*100)}}%</p>
          <p class="rec_small">C: {{report.co*100}}%</p>
          <p class="rec_small">E: {{report.ex*100}}%</p>
          <p class="rec_small">A: {{report.ag*100}}%</p>
          <p class="rec_small">N: {{report.ne*100}}%</p>
        
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters between pages is usually using the URL, since this method is showed to the end user, I suggest not include any passwords or something like that

In the link you will redirect the user ends in something like

```
<a class="text" href="/applicant-report?phone={{a.phone}}">
```

Where the `a.phone` is the value of your variable. To read this url in the other page, you use something like

```
applicant_phone = request.args.get('phone')
applicant = session.query(Applicant).filter_by(phone=applicant_phone).first()
```

If you want to add another parameter to the url you concat using `&` between them, like

```
<a class="text" href="/applicant-report?phone={{a.phone}}&{{a.contact}}">
```

And so on.

Hope you find this usefull